# Rotating laser mounted on a vehicle

Tags: ros, 2dlaserscan, laserscanner, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I obtained 3d point cloud using 2d rotating laser scanner on a base frame . But now I want to this  mounted on a vehicle. How can I do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276527/rotating-laser-mounted-on-a-vehicle/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2017-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2017-11-23**:
I'm guess the answer I'd give right now is "Mount it on a vehicle", but I guess you're interested in some more specific (hopefully ROS-related) information. You might want to edit your question accordingly.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-11-23**:
I do not need to do anything on the code if I mount my laserscanner on a vehicle? do not I have to create a moving tf instead of a fixed tf? because now, my laserscanner rotating on a base frame like this https://hizliresim.com/Mab1D6
I also sent a mail you about this problem Mr. Kohlbrecher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recommended way would be adding the LIDAR setup to the URDF model of your robot. You can find the URDF tutorials [here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials). You then just need to publish the required joint state for the rotating joint of your setup and you should be all set.

A (perhaps relatively complex) real-world example is the rotating LIDAR macro we use for our Tracker robot. See [tracker_spinning_lidar_mount.urdf.xacro.xml](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_tracker_common/blob/master/hector_tracker_description/urdf/tracker_spinning_lidar_mount.urdf.xacro.xml). The macro is instantiated (i.e. used for actually adding the rotating LIDAR to the robot model) [here in tracker_structure_addons.urdf.xacro.xml](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_tracker_common/blob/master/hector_tracker_description/urdf/tracker_structure_addons.urdf.xacro.xml#L145). Note this setup is relatively complex because it also provides ability to define calibration of the LIDAR on the spindle as well as full Gazebo simulation capability.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-11-24**:
I have already created a basic urdf according to the model I showed in the picture.
file:///home/ahmet/catkin_ws/src/lidar_package/urdf/tilt_mech.urdf (thats my urdf model) I will put this model on a golf car. how do I edit this code? I am so sorry I am very new about ROS.

**Comment by [singhv](https://answers.ros.org/users/56518/singhv/) on 2021-03-09**:
@Mekateng how did you achieved 3d point cloud from 2d tilted scanner?i am also trying to do same thing using laser assembler but assembled point cloud are in single plane not in 3d. what should i do fix it?